# how to skip malformed packet when using lxml's iterparse?

Tags: python, malformed, iterparse

I have some very huge xml files (>50G) converted from wireshark. When using iterparse to extract information from these files, I found there are some malformed packets that cause the iterparse report error which says:

for event, elem in context:
  File "iterparse.pxi", line 207, in lxml.etree.iterparse.**next** (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:126122)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Specification mandate value for attribute p, line 285430929, column 50

What can I do just to skip these malformed packets and proceed to parse?

Comment: @salparadise wouldn't help here

Comment: try using `recover='ignore'` in the parser.